# Выбор основного видеокарты AMD

Tags: windows, драйвер, amd, видеокарта, radeon

Я купил новый компьютер в нем установлен **Amd Radeon(tm)R530**. Я установил некие программы графические, GTA5 т.д. Так ошибок вижу то, что видеокарта слабая так далее(VRAM). Я захожу в настройки AMD там такая у меня проблема: Основная аппаратура: 80MB Vram(слабая). Другая подключенная: 2048 MB VRAM Так далее. А используется слабая(основная) везде. Как исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть вам необходимо сделать основной более мощную видеокарту, чтобы приложения использовали только её? Попробуйте отключить «слабую» видеокарту через BIOS либо Диспетчер устройств. **Внимание: перед отключением чего-либо в «Диспетчере ...» убедитесь, что вы можете и знаете как загружать Windows в безопасном режиме — только в нём вы сможете включить всё обратно, если ОС перестанет загружаться.**

Comment: Я сделал как вы сказали но получал ошибки так далее. все что то не то стало обратно включил